# Sort list of str into pairs of str where one str has -R

Tags: python

I have a list of string that goes like:

`["A TB", "A-R TB", "B TB", "B-R TB", "C TB", "C-R TB" ...]`

but the order of the strings are random. How do I write a function that pairs up the elements so the output looks like:

```
[["A TB", "A-R TB"], ["B TB", "B-R TB"], ["C TB", "C-R TB"] ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just sort the list lexicographically, then read it pairwise:

```
def grouped(lst):
    i = iter(sorted(lst))
    return list(zip(i, i))
```

Another alternative is to use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
def grouped(lst):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst), lambda x: x[0])]
```

This way you can have groups of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 1):

You can group string by their values without `'-R'`. Then you can construct your desired list.

```
import re, collections
xs = ["A TB", "A-R TB", "B TB", "B-R TB", "C TB", "C -R TB"]
occurences = collections.defaultdict(list)
exp = re.compile(' *-R')
for x in xs:
    occurences[exp.sub('', x)].append(x)

res = list(occurences.values())
print(res)
# [['A TB', 'A-R TB'], ['B TB', 'B-R TB'], ['C TB', 'C -R TB']]
```

Comment: The resulting list is not guaranteed to be ordered as dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: @eugeney, there is no requirement to have ordered output.

Answer (score 0):

I used your specific input for this. If the input is more generic please tell me.

```
def part(l):
    result = []
    has_r = sorted([item for item in l if "-R" in item])
    no_r = sorted([item for item in l if "-R" not in item])
    for r, no_r in zip(has_r, no_r):
        if r.replace("-R", "") == no_r:
            result.append([no_r, r])
    return result
```

And the results:

```
inp = ["A TB", "A-R TB", "B TB", "B-R TB", "C TB", "C-R TB"]
print(part(inp))

[['A TB', 'A-R TB'], ['B TB', 'B-R TB'], ['C TB', 'C-R TB']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about order and only want to group them based on the first letter (becuase that's not clear):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ["A TB", "A-R TB", "B TB", "B-R TB", "C TB", "C -R TB"]
b = defaultdict(list)
c = []

for x in a:
    b[x[0]].append(x)
for x in b.values():
    c.append(x)
print(c)
# [['C -R TB', 'C TB'], ['B TB', 'B-R TB'], ['A TB', 'A-R TB']]
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it, but definitely not the only way is to sort the list by the first two letters, then take pairs of two elements. Something like this:

```
ino = ["A TB", "A-R TB", "B TB", "B-R TB", "C TB", "C -R TB"]
ina = sorted(into, key=lambda x: x[0:1])
out = list(zip(ina, ina[1:]))[0::2]
print(out)
# Shows [('A TB', 'A-R TB'), ('B TB', 'B-R TB'), ('C TB', 'C -R TB')]
```

I assumed there's only one occurrence of a pair in the stream. This breaks down if there's more, however.

The magic line is `out = list(zip(ina, ina[1:]))[0::2]`. What it does is pair each element in the original list, with the original list but without its head. So we get an iterator where the first element is paired with the second, the second with the third, the third with the fourth etc. We're only interested in the even elements, that is, the first element with the second, the third with the fourth etc, so we use `[0::2]` to select every other element from the `0`th to the end.